# Why does intellisense miss classes?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why are certain classes missing from intellisense?

I like intellisense, it is handy.  It is also puzzling.  Certain objects are missing and I do not know if I have some setting set incorrectly or that is just "how it is."

```
    Dim DR As DataGridViewPaintParts "This class appears.
    Dim DR As DataGridViewRow 'This class does not appear, although the others do.
    Dim DR As DataGridViewRowContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs 'This class also appears.
```

I would presume that the DataGridViewRow is more widely used than the other two, maybe I'm wrong.  But in any event, why does it not appear for me?

Comment: No repro for me, but I'm in C#.  Perhaps it's because VB's syntax is a bit more ambiguous, or the VB team decided to show some classes but not others.

Comment: Note the Common and All tabs at the bottom of the popup window.  You need All to see everything.  Not terribly consistent in what it filters, this feature was removed in recent VS versions.

Comment: @Hans, Kudos to you, thanks.  I didn't even see that.  If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

Hans Passant actually answered the question in his comment:

> Note the Common and All tabs at the bottom of the popup window. You need All to see everything. Not terribly consistent in what it filters, this feature was removed in recent VS versions.